# I am using django crispy forms how can I change this text to start from the top and get to the below line when the line is full

Tags: html, css, django

So guys my site looks like this right now.

Here's the site! You will definitely understand my problem if you didn't from the title,
[image: Screenshot]

HTML

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3" id="ada">
        <h3>Makale Ekle</h3>
        <hr>
        <form method = "post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            
            {{form|crispy}}
            <br>
            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger">Ekle</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: rebeccapurple;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


#ada {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-top: 5rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
    border: 5px solid rgb(49, 2, 68);
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
}

label {
    color: white;
}

input {
    width: 800px;
    margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
    size: 2rem;
    border: 3px solid purple;
    text-align: justify;
}

input[name="context"] {
    height: 10rem;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

So guys I think I am missing something easy.
I tried to solve it by adding some code in CSS but it definitely didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the TextArea widget at forms.py

I can give an example.

forms.py

```
def class FeedbackForm(forms.Form):
     title = forms.CharField(label="Title",widget=forms.TextInput)
     message = forms.CharField(label="Message", widget=forms.Textarea)
```

[image: feedback form]